# python: loop not working

Tags: python, for-loop

I have written the following piece of code in a python script. It doesn't seem to loop over all the lines of the input file, but executes only for the 1st line.

```
while linecount1>0:
    line=images.readline().split()
    query=queries.readline().split()

    for word1 in line:
        count+=1
        for word2 in query:
            x='java -cp "lib/*:esalib.jar" clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer %s %s' % (word1, word2)
            args=shlex.split(x)
            print args
            p=subprocess.Popen(args)
            p.wait()
            #print p
            f=open("result",'r')
            sim=f.readline()
            temp.write(str(word1)+" ")
            temp.write(str(word2)+"\n")
            #print value
        if word1==word2:
            score=score+(3*float(sim))/2
            same+=1
        else:
            score=score+float(sim)
    linecount1=linecount1-1
```

The code works fine but only for the first line of the file "images". But does not iterate through all the lines. Note that file "images" has multiple lines, and each line has multiple words. While the file "query" has a single line

What am i doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of doing `while linecount1 > 0`, do `for line in images:`. It won't solve your problem, but it makes your code easier to understand and therefore easier to debug.

Comment: You said it yourself. query only has one line, but in round 2 of the while loop you are trying to read its line nr 2 :)